# AWS lambda throws: Unable to import module 'index': libta_lib.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory on ta-lib Python project

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, ta-lib

I use ta-lib in my Python project and I wanted to execute some code in AWS Lambdas. Ta-lib requires cython library to be installed so I was following the guide from ta-lib github
https://github.com/TA-Lib/ta-lib-python

Lambda and layers works on Python 3.10. Required environment variables in lambda are set up in correct way.

I built locally the application and checked if it was working - no errors. I moved files which were built locally to lambda in the same structure they were built in my local and tried to execute some code. Result should be the data my application returns but instead of I received error:

```
"errorMessage": "Unable to import module 'index': libta_lib.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory",
/python/lib/libta_lib.so.0
/python/talib/libta_lib.so.0
/python/libta_lib.so.0
```